# Change the datatype of a column in a dataframe from factor in date in R

Tags: r, date, types

I have the following dataframe (df1)

```
Date        A       B       C       D       E     

2000-10-04  6857    68964   6760    6823    6823    
2000-10-05  6819    6917    6819    6892    6892    
2000-10-06  6895    6921    6712    6776    6776
```

I want to change the datatype of column "Date" from factor to date.

Comment: Share your data with `dput()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the whole column with mutate and use the as.Date function. The format of your data is `'%Y-%m-%d'`. A list of formats can be found [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3/topics/strptime)

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: Don't forget to include the libraries you used, in this case ´dplyr`.

Answer (score 0):

I also highly recommend the `lubridate` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date))
```

This make it much easier and you don't have to remember the date formats.